# How to use angular two binding for dynamically created Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, telerik, kendo-grid

Actually i am creating the whole grid dynamically. In that i need to achieve two way binding using angularjs.

I have looked many examples unable to find releted my requirement.

Here i am attaching one example for two binding concept. but this not my real requrement code. that is very difficult to create dojo. So i attached this Dojo Link.

In this link when ever updating existing data it's updating to the Kendo datasource as well as $scope value. but if i add any new record then it's updating only kendo datasource not updating the $scope. Please give me the solution for this based on this i think i can able to achieve my requirement.

Thanks in advance...

http://dojo.telerik.com/aTIba/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achived two way binding for this.http://dojo.telerik.com/aTIba/9